# Bootstrap collapse not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a simple collapse which I have it in many place and works. In this scenario, I am building the child list through Jquery and not sure why the collapse is not working. Any help here

This is my parent div which has the anchor tag as below

```
<a href="#" style="margin-right: 30px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#147" aria-expanded="true">PROJECT</a>
```

The child is as below which is generated through jQuery. This list is not expanding as expected

```
<ul class="collapse" id="147" style="height: 0px;"><li>...</li></ul>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle that reproduces the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Please check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3z1xdm7L/1/

When I click 'PROJECT', its not expanding or dont see any action but in the debugger it says collapse in and collapse as expected

Comment: you are missing both `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js`, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c0ojy17/)

Comment: @dippas Thanks for adding those. When I add the hyperlink under href instead of data-target, it works in the fiddle but not the same in my application

Comment: can someone guide me here

Comment: I'm a bit confused; do you have a fiddle that reproduces the problem now?

Comment: I found the issue. It was due to the div surrounding this navbar had a collapse class and that was restricting the collapse behavior.